# how to assign a static ip when isp keeps on shifting ip's and there is no LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, ip

My ISP keeps on giving new ips every time i connect to the internet. I have no LAN specified and don't need one as of now. Is there any way with which i can have a static ip of my system every time i connect to internet i.e. same public ip every time?

EDIT: See i have a small company and have systems there but no LAN as of now. Now i want certain documents (saved on my internet server) to be opened up in my office only. But my office ISP gives new ips everytime that is why i need a solution with which i can assign static ips to those systems and can restrict that document to be opened up only on those office systems.

Comment: Yes, get a router and leave it on, also make sure your power doesn't come off.

Comment: this is not possible in my situation

Comment: You can get a static IP from your ISP. If you are using ADSL connection or like such, everytime you connect to the internet your IP gets changed

Answer (score 4):

If you really NEED a constant IP for your computer, you can always ask your ISP for one, though this cna be a very expensive service.

Another option is to "simulate" this behavior through a [dynamic DNS service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), such as www.no-ip.com or http://dyn.com/dns/. It associates a domain to your computer (something like iamtheguy.no-ip.com).
This usually requires to install some software on your computer, so that every time your "real" public IP changes, this is notified to the external dynamic DNS server.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to "set" your ip to a static one. But you could use a service like [DynDNS](http://dyndns.org).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at something like this [DYNDns](http://dyn.com/dns/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).

Looks nice. Also, I found it awhile ago reading [this](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2012-08/15-tunnel_a_local_webserver_to_the_internet) interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your ISP for a static IP - I pay £5 (GBP) per month for mine.

The only other way, if that isn't an option, have your webservice require a username / password when the request comes from an IP that isn't current - This then updates your app to automatically allow requests from the approved IP.

If your IP changes then you'll need a username / password to access again.

However, with this I'd use a strong cookie as well, so that the next person who get's assigned your old IP can't access it for free - i.e. you need both the correct cookie and IP address to access without a username / password.